# What is contact in "from contact in xml.Descendants("Group")" linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq to xml in my project but still not getting some concepts.

Comment: Please read `from clause` on MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from contact in xml.Descendants("Group")
...
```

In that piece of code, `contact` is known as the "range variable". It will take the value of each element returned by `xml.Descendants("Group")`, like the variable in a `foreach` loop. Since `xml.Descendants("Group")` returns a sequence of `XElement`s, the type of `contact` is `XElement`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it'll be an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx). You can tell by hovering the mouse over the word `contact`. As [alexn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41596/alexn) says, ready up on the [from clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx)